# How to add a field to an existing map field in Firestore using flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

There is a map in Firestore. I have another map by the name `correctAnswersNew` that I wish to add to this existing map `correctAnswers`. Something like this:

```
await mycollection
      .doc("1")
      .update('correctAnswers' : correctAnswersNew).then(
          (value) => null);
```

For array it is easy using `FieldValue.arrayUnion`, but is there any option for map also ?

Comment: so you want to add an map value to the exist correctAnswer collection in firebase?, ig you can make another collection into the correctAnswer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a new value to an existing map value like this:

```
await mycollection
      .doc("1")
      .update({
  'correctAnswers.correctAnswersNew': correctAnswersNew,
});
```